# LR v11.5 - Application not opening during recording

Tags: loadrunner

When I manually punch the URL of the application in the browser, application is getting opened up without any problem.

But when I am trying to capture/Record script using LR 11.5, browser is getting invoked by LR but, application is not getting opened up in the browser.

I am getting -  "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"  message in the browser.

Below are the other details:

```
OS:  Window 2008 R2 Server
Browser : IE 8
Vugen Version:  11.5
Protocol :  Web(HTTP/HTML)
Application:  Web application is developed using Web2.0 technologies like Javascript, JQuery, Ajax...etc.
```

could anyone shed some light on it...?

Please help...!

-srini

Comment: Srini, did you solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008_R2

Windows 2008 R2 is a 64 Bit operating system.   VUGEN is a 32 bit application.   Please see release notes regarding the recording of applications in a 64 bit environment.

Comment: James, Will this really impact the web applications? or is it only for client-server applications?

Comment: Read the release notes.  Yes, it specifically mentions recording in a 64 bit environment.   There are technical issues at play here related to a 32 bit application (VUGEN) hooking a 64 bit application, be it a browser or thick client.   A 32 bit virtual machine works just fine for recording.  Don't use it for execution, but for recording and script development it works just fine.

Comment: James, In my case its a browser based web application and LoadRunner is failing to open the application in the browser(Browser is getting successfully invoked by VuGen) for recording.

Comment: Try it on a 32 bit environment

Answer (score 0):

As per Release notes:
***Recording of 64bit applications has been added to the existing support for 64bit operating systems. 64bit applications can usually be recognized when the ‘*32’ suffix is not displayed in the Windows Task Manager for their process. Replay is in 32bit.***

I just tried recording a web app using vugen*32 and I was able to record using both IE and IE 64bit. I am on Windows 2008 R2 Standard SP1 64 bit OS.

Please see if using a supported version of FF you are able to record.